# Might the word "including" mean "additionally" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, conjunctions

**"Kuwait - which has a population of 4.8 million, including 3.4 million foreign workers - has the world's sixth-largest known oil reserves.**" [BBC-Kuwait](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-67736721)

The word **"including"** confuses me, because include means to consider as a part of something. And it also means adding something (or someone) to a category or group.

So, to me, as a non-native English speaker, such a sentence might be ambiguous.

To sum up, does this sentence mean: *The population is 4.8 million Kuwaitis and there are also additionally 3.4 million foreigners (non-citizens), which makes a total of 8.2 million people currently living in the country?*

Or does it mean; *The population is **4.8 million**, and **3.4 million of this number** is foreign workers, and the number of Kuwaiti citizens are actually **1.4 million** people*?

Comment: Population itself refers to the people live in a particular country so it should be clear that foreign workers also live in that country.

Comment: But then the number of foreign workers are more than twice the number of citizens, which is a little bit weird. Just imagine, the UK population is 67 million. And if I write the same sentence structure for UK, here is the weird situation:  "UK - which has a population of 67 million, including 20 million foreign workers". Such a sentence would not seem to make sense, would it? This is why I couldn't make sure if I understood the sentence correctly.

Comment: This is the very dictionary definition of the word 'including'. What makes it incomprehensible? Is it just that you are surprised a country could contain more migrant workers than native? This is not unusual in the Emirates, or anywhere on the 'oily side' of the Gulf. See [Dubai](https://worldpopulationreview.com/world-cities/dubai-population) where only 15% of the population is native.

Comment: Google says *Most of the country's population reside in the urban agglomeration of the capital and largest city Kuwait City. As of 2022, Kuwait has a population of 4.45 million people **of which 1.45 million are Kuwaiti citizens** while the remaining **3.00 million are foreign nationals** from over 100 countries.* Just because *Britain* wouldn't welcome 130 million immigrants doesn't mean Kuwait has the same attitude.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. Thanks for the comment. Yes, that is why I wasn't sure of myself. I couldn't imagine a place where the foreigners 2,5 times more than the citizens. That is one reason. But then the word including also seems to have a meaning of "additionaly". See the meaning of "include" on https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/include

Comment: Look it up in other dictionaries. 'add as part of something else' does not mean what you seem to think it means. It's almost 'intermix', not 'in addition to'

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Great writing. Your sentence structure is so clear -better than the BBC editor :) - and leaves no doubt on the side of us, non-native English speakers. By the way, the structure ".....of which...." is a very good way of emphasizing the situation without creating a vague sense of "additionally".

Comment: So far as I can see, there wasn't (or at least, *shouldn't* have been) a problem with the meaning of the word ***including*** in your cited BBC text. The italicized text in my previous comment was just cut&pasted from the first "snippet view" after googling **kuwait population**. Presumably if you'd done that yourself, you wouldn't have been confused by the BBC text - which it seems you only struggled with because you didn't think the literal meaning was ***likely***. Is that correct?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, yes that is almost correct. I couldn't imagine such a situation - there being 2,5 times more foreigners than the citizens. So I looked up the word "to include", and found the meaning "to add". So, I thought "including" might mean "additionally" in that sentence, but still as a non-native speaker I was not 100% sure, which is why I wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning here means that the 4.8 million includes the count of 3.4 million.  That is there are 4.8-3.4 = 1.4 million Kuwaitis who are not foreign workers.

That the number of foreign workers is larger than the number of citizens is notable, but not so unusual in the region.  The same is true in the UAE, in which citizens form about 10-15% of the population, most are foreign residents.